# How to connect RocksDB using java

Tags: java, database, rocksdb

I have to connect Rocksdb cluster using java programme with credentials and then it has to read and write from the DB

Comment: Try this link: https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/wiki/RocksJava-Basics

Comment: What is meant by path/to/db in                  final RocksDB db = RocksDB.open(options, "path/to/db")

Comment: Rocksdb is stored in files on disk. It means you find and give that path to the database you want to read